# YouTube Integration in my App with gridview and adapters

Tags: android, youtube-api

I have a certain issue that I am trying to work around. Any Advice would be awesome.

I already know how to integrate the youtube player and thumbnails into my main activity in android studio. However I want to do it a different way and have done quite a lot of research on it and have come up short.

My Issue:
I want to create a Gridview in my main activity, then create a seperate row layout and adapter to use with the gridview in the main activity so that I can display multiple thumbnails at a time.
The thing is that my Adapter class already extends "ArrayAdapter" and in order for my adapter to set a different "VIDEO_ID" for each thumbnail, I need it to extend "YouTubeBaseActivity" so that I can use:

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView,
                                    YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader)"
```

the method within my adapter.
However, I know in JAVA that you can only inherit from one class.

So can anyone give me some advice on a possible workaround?

Code that I require assistance on:

- The MainActivity:

  public class FanHome extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
              YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener, YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener {
          private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
          private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
          private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView;
              private YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader;

  ```
  private String[] tempVideos = {"Video1","Video2","Video3","Video4","Video5","Video6","Video7"
                                  ,"Video8","Video9","Video10"};

  @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_fan_home);
   ListAdapter theAdapter = new VideoGridAdapter(this,tempVideos);
      GridView theGridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridViewYoutubeThumbnails);
      theGridView.setAdapter(theAdapter);

   youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView)findViewById(R.id.youtubethumb);
      youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
      youTubeThumbnailView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {

    }});
  }
  ```
- The VideoGridAdapter:

  ```
  public class VideoGridAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  public VideoGridAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
      super(context, R.layout.row_grid_videos, values);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater theInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
      final View theView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid_videos, parent, false);
      String videoSelected = getItem(position);

      if (videoSelected.equals("Video1")) {
          String VIDEO_ID = "o7VVHhK9zf0";
      }

      return theView;
  }
  ```
- The row_grid_videos layout:

  ```
  <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
      android:id="@+id/youtubethumb"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="5dp" />

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/panelPraisePurge"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="bottom"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:paddingLeft="5dp"
      android:paddingRight="5dp">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/imageViewDislike"
              android:layout_width="20dp"
              android:layout_height="20dp"
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_purge" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewDislike"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="25" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="right"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/imageView2"
              android:layout_width="20dp"
              android:layout_height="20dp"
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_praise" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="50" />
      </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
  ```
- The MainAcitivity layout

  ```
  <GridView
      android:id="@+id/gridViewYoutubeThumbnails"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:numColumns="auto_fit">
  </GridView>
  ```

Comment: Please post the code instead of explaining the code you tried

Comment: It's a bit complicated to just post the one section

Comment: May have found a possible soltuion: https://androidtutorialmagic.wordpress.com/my-mini-project/multiple-youtube-video-in-recyclerviewlistview-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great, I found the solution to my issue.
https://androidtutorialmagic.wordpress.com/my-mini-project/multiple-youtube-video-in-recyclerviewlistview-in-android/

This website above explains how to use an Adapter to Call in Thumbnails from "known" youtube videos. However it sets it in a list format instead of a grid format. So the only thing that needs to be changed in the above website is:

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

To:

```
 GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```